# Efficient way to read Mmap

Tags: go, system-calls, mmap

I am using `syscall` to read a byte array out of `mmap`:

```
file, e := os.Open(path)
if e != nil {...}
defer file.Close()

fi, e := file.Stat()
if e != nil {...}
data, e := syscall.Mmap(int(file.Fd()), 0, int(fi.Size()), syscall.PROT_READ, syscall.MAP_SHARED)
if e != nil {...}
```

`data` is the binary array I need.

I am using `||` as a delimiter, so I can get slices by using `bytes.Split`:

```
slices := bytes.Split(data, []byte("||"))
for _, s := range slices {
    str := string(s[:])
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

This works fine, and I also stored the total number of messages (its type is `uint32` which takes 8 bytes) at the beginning of the `mmap`.

When a new message is written in, I can get the total number of messages by reading the first 8 bytes.

Assuming I have the number of messages as `n`, I still need to do the following to read the new message:

```
slices := bytes.Split(data, []byte("||"))
s := slices[n - 1]
str := string(s[:])
fmt.Println(str)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `bytes.Split` can be very expensive. To choose an appropriate data structure we need to know what you are tryng to accomplish. The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: If the messages are not fixed-length, there is a definite limit to how efficient this can be; getting message *n* will always require reading every message from 0..n, and parsing every character looking for the delimiter (whether you do this with `Split` or some other method).

Comment: You could use msgpack for the internal repsentation of your data.